# How to create and use index?

Tags: android, sqlite, search, indexing

I have SQLite database table. While searching it is very slow.  It takes 20-30 seconds to find appropriate words.  Reason is I am using(I have to) join and 2-3 WHERE clauses in my query.

```
query = "SELECT" + " e.id AS _id," + " ke.id AS ke_id,"
                + " ke.fk as ke_fk," + " ke.value as ke_value,"
                + " re.id AS ke_id," + " re.fk as re_fk,"
                + " re.value as re_value," + " s.id AS  s_id,"
                + " s.fk as s_fk," + " g.id AS g_id," + " g.fk as g_fk,"
                + " g.lang," + " g.value as g_value" + " FROM entry e"
                + "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk"
                + "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk"
                + "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk"
                + "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk"
                + " WHERE g.lang IS NULL AND g.value like '"
                + lookingFor + "%'  GROUP BY g.value LIMIT 5";
```

This is relationship between tables:
[image]

I have read about index(primary, unique). I know about ordering values while indexing. My question is how to create(I am not talking about create PRIMARY UNIQUE INDEX for id, I am talking about not id column where search will be held) and USE that index to speed up search query? Programmatically or in Aplication(SQLite Expert Professional)?If I create index does it create index every time when search is made?

Please give your opinions or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use transactions at all?

Comment: Excuse me, but how can it help me?

Comment: What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query?

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is very slow in any case and does not use indices (correct me if I am wrong). If your goal is some full text search look at FTS3 capability of SQLite. There are numerous samples out there. For example: [FTS3 blog](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/)